# How to call a Matlab function in Python from matlab.engine using the user's input (variable of type string) as the name of the function?

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-engine

I have a Matlab function name as a string (the variable name is 'function_name'), which is an input from a user, and I need to somehow call that function from Python. Below you can see how I was trying to call this function using the variable name, but it exited with the following error: `(<class 'matlab.engine.MatlabExecutionError'>, MatlabExecutionError("Undefined function 'chsn_agthm' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.\n"), <traceback object at 0x0000015D14323C00>)`

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
res = eng.function_name(input1, input2, nargout=2)
```

Comment: You might try ```res = eng.feval( function_name, input1, input2, nargout=2)```, with ```function_name```  being a string of an *existing* MATLAB function. I cannot test myself, so if it is working, feedback would be welcome.

Comment: If it is working, I would upgrade the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `function_name` needs to be a statement in the python code, but is given as string. To resolve this, my suggestion would be not to call `function_name` directly, but to always call MATLAB's `feval` function with `function_name` as first input argument, i.e.

```
res = eng.feval( function_name, input1, input2, nargout=2)
```

`feval` is then called by the MATLAB engine and invokes the function with the name `function_name` using the other arguments (apart from `nargout=2`) as input.

For further information on `feval` please have a look at https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html.

*Alternative approach:*

It might also be possible to construct a string that contains a valid python expression including `function_name` and then to call this expression using pythons `eval()`.